# Inverse trignometric functions in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to find out where is the trignomatric function $Arccos(z)$ holomorphic in the complex plane! Now knowing that $Arccos(z)$=$(1/i)Log( z + \sqrt{ z^2 -1} )$ with $Log$ being the principal usual complex Logarithem and the square root too being principal. Starting from this expression, its known that $Arccos (z)$ is holomorphic thus where the principal $Log$ and Square root are holomorphic! Starting from the square root function, we know it's holomorphic on the Complex plane without the negative Real part of it i.e $R-$ so solving $z^2 -1 \le 0 $ gives us as a solution of $z$ the whole imaginary axis and the segment of the Real axis [-1,1]. Now as for the holomorphity of $Log$, we shall solve the equation $z + \sqrt{z^2-1} \le x$ knowing that $x \le 0$ and i got that$ z$= ${x^2 +1}\over{2x}$ with $x$ being negative! My question is that can i deduce that the whole negative real part with the union of the the segment [0,1] of the Real axis and the union of the whole Imaginary axis compose the set where $Arccos(z)$ is not holomorphic at?